# Calculating the integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

The question is asked in the [mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990522/calculating-the-integral). There is no answer. I can't solve it by hand, also.
Maybe we can solve it with Mathematica.
[image]

Appreciate all your help, effort.

Best regards.

```
  \[Psi][0][τ]:=  Piecewise[{{0,  t<0}, { 1-t/h}}];
      \[Psi][n][τ]:=  Piecewise[{{0,  t < T-h, {1-(T-t)/h}}];
         \[Psi][i][τ]:=   Piecewise[{(t-(i-h)*h)/h],(i-1)*h<=t<=i*h},{((i+1)*h-t)/h,i*h<=t<=(i+1)*h }}];
    
        ((ρ+1)^(1-α)/(Gamma[α]))*Integrate[(z^(ρ+1)-τ^(ρ+1))^(α-1)*τ^ρ*\[Psi][i][τ], τ];
```

Comment: What have you tried using Mathematica? Please post any code, so that we can copy and paste it.

Comment: The actual antiderivatives involved here are `Integrate[(z^(ρ+1)-τ^(ρ+1))^(α-1)*τ^ρ, τ]` (simple) and `Integrate[(z^(ρ+1)-τ^(ρ+1))^(α-1)*τ^ρ*τ, τ]` (hypergeometric), which can both be done by Mathematica. The tricky bit is the bookkeeping of coefficients and indices $i,j$.